Inferring schema from a pyarrow dataframe created with parquet file is giving wrong data type for a column
I have a parquet file which is loaded into pandas dataframe as below.
df = pq.read_table("full_file.parquet")

and If I check the column types in the schema, as below, for some columns it is showing type as null
for i in df.schema:
    print(i.name, i.type)

and the data in that column is all nulls.If I create a redshift table with that above schema and for null, I provided text type and tried copying data using copy command with the same file from s3 bucket, it is throwing below error.
Spectrum Scan Error. File 'https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev-env-bucket/full_file.parquet' has an incompatible Parquet schema for column 's3://dev-env-bucket/full_file.parquet.colname'. Column type: VARCHAR, Parquet schema: optional int32 colname
Why am I not getting exact data type for the column from parquet file in dataframe? Why am I getting null instead.
